# i18n with jinja2 + GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, internationalization, gettext, jinja2

I googled for a GAE + jinja i18n example but could not find it. Can anyone provide a link or working example?

My effort uses the django translations and I don't know if this is the recommend way of doing it.

```
import jinja2
from django.utils import translation
from django.utils.translation import gettext, ngettext, ugettext, ungettext, get_language, activate
class DjangoTranslator(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.gettext = gettext
        self.ngettext = ngettext
        self.ugettext = ugettext
        self.ungettext = ungettext
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
class DjangoEnvironment(jinja2.Environment):

    def get_translator(self, context):
        return DjangoTranslator()

jinja_environment = DjangoEnvironment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)), extensions=['jinja2.ext.i18n'])
jinja_environment.install_gettext_translations(translation)
```

Thanks for any hint or advice. I also use a custom request handler for i18n:

```
from django.utils import translation

class I18NHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def render_template(self, file, template_args):
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates',
                            file)
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_args))

    def initialize(self, request, response):
        webapp2.RequestHandler.initialize(self, request, response)
        self.request.COOKIES = Cookies(self)
        self.request.META = os.environ
        self.reset_language()

    def reset_language(self):

        # Decide the language from Cookies/Headers

        language = translation.get_language_from_request(self.request)
        translation.activate(language)
        self.request.LANGUAGE_CODE = translation.get_language()

        # Set headers in response
        self.response.headers['Content-Language'] = str(translation.get_language())
```

Comment: jinja2 is for the new (experimental) python 2.7, not stable yet. dJango 1.2 runs on python2.5. Have you googled `django i18n example`? Lots of [sample](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter18/) help page?

Answer (score 3):

Another blog post on how to [Enable jinja2 and i18n translations on Google AppEngine](http://mikeshilkov.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/enable-jinja2-and-i18n-translations-on-google-appengine/)

It's kind of more detailed with all the steps needed to run jinja2 + i18n.